# How to Smooth Slide Transition to Next/Previous YouTube Playlist Videos? YouTube API (Fiddle Included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am wondering if anyone would have any suggestions. I am wanting to have a single YouTube playlist embedded as a slider, with smooth-transitioning previous and next prompts, (or buttons). I have a Fiddle that presents the core functionality of this thus far, but now I am looking for some sort of solution which would allow for a smooth sliding/carousel transition, right (to reveal previous videos) and left (for more recent videos). Any ideas?

Here's my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dwqawm21/

Otherwise, you can run/test the snippet below:

```js
var App = App || {};

App.YoutubePlaylistLoader = {

  resultsTarget: null,

  xhr: null,

  apiBase: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',

  prevPageToken: null,
  nextPageToken: null,

  results: null,

  params: {
    maxResults: 1,
    playlistId: 'BhKKjnUR0XB8DwQwXqBsChb48E8jzfr-',
    key: 'AIzaSyCO9WXh_74m7ATK50P0vegWRQwjVADShmA',
    part: 'contentDetails,snippet',
    pageToken: null
  },

  init: function(resultsTarget) {
    var _this = App.YoutubePlaylistLoader;

    _this.resultsTarget = resultsTarget;
    _this.resultsTarget.on('click', '.youtube-result', _this.onResultClick);

    _this.getPlaylistItems();
  },

  previousPage: function() {
    var _this = App.YoutubePlaylistLoader;
    if (!_this.prevPageToken) {
      return false;
    }
    _this.params.pageToken = _this.prevPageToken;
    _this.getPlaylistItems();
  },

  nextPage: function() {
    var _this = App.YoutubePlaylistLoader;
    if (!_this.nextPageToken) {
      return false;
    }
    _this.params.pageToken = _this.nextPageToken;
    _this.getPlaylistItems();
  },

  getPlaylistItems: function() {
    var _this = App.YoutubePlaylistLoader;

    _this.resultsTarget.html('');

    _this.xhr && _this.xhr.abort();

    _this.xhr = $.ajax({
      url: _this.apiBase + '/playlistItems',
      data: _this.params,
      success: function(response) {

        _this.prevPageToken = response.prevPageToken;
        _this.nextPageToken = response.nextPageToken;

        if (response.items) {
          _this.processResults(response.items);
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, errorThrown, textStatus) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  },

  processResults: function(results) {
    var _this = App.YoutubePlaylistLoader;
    _this.results = results;

    var resultsHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < _this.results.length; i++) {
      var result = _this.results[i];
      resultsHTML += [
        '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-video-id="',
        result.contentDetails.videoId,
        '" class="youtube-result">',
        '<img src=' + (
          result.snippet.thumbnails.medium ?
          result.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url :
          result.snippet.thumbnails.default.url
        ) + '>',
        '<strong>' + result.snippet.title + '</strong>',
        '<span class="clearfix"></span>',
        '</a>'
      ].join('');
    }

    _this.resultsTarget.html(resultsHTML);

  },

  onResultClick: function() {
    var _this = App.YoutubePlaylistLoader;
    var videoId = $(this).data('video-id');
    window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoId, '_system');
  }

};

$(function() {
  App.YoutubePlaylistLoader.init($('#results'));
});
```

```css
.clearfix {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.youtube-result {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #EEE;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.youtube-result:active {
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.youtube-result strong {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font: bold 13pt sans-serif;
}

.youtube-result img {
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.youtube-result+.youtube-result {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="App.YoutubePlaylistLoader.previousPage()">Prev</button>
<button type="button" onclick="App.YoutubePlaylistLoader.nextPage()">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your Fiddle and added smooth sliding/fading.

https://jsfiddle.net/canaanites/k5mybrgu/

The trick:

I have created two classes. one for fading and the other for sliding.

```
<div id="results" class="fadeIn slide"></div>
```

So far so good, except one problem. The CSS animation will only be applied once at the beginning. The below code solves the problem.

```
_this.resultsTarget.removeClass("slide");
setTimeout(function(){ _this.resultsTarget.addClass("slide"); }, 10);
```

**UPDATE:** changed the fiddle link & and the code a bit

Comment: Thanks for your input! Indeed, a slide-in fade effect was applied, but this seems to have disabled the functionality of navigating to the next/previous video in the playlist. Currently, it just remains on the first video in the list, even when clicking the next button...

Comment: Also, the animation/transition I am seeking for is more of a carousel effect, where the first item of the playlist would remain static, and the next/previous prompted items would slide to replace it (left to right, and vice versa). I guess I should not have mentioned fading in my question, so I will edit that out.

Comment: @NR159 I have updated the answer. It should work now